# Generar valor al azar con parametros predeterminados

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, random

Primero expongo el código:

```
import random
from random import choice

exclude = ['A9', 'B2', 'C18']
let = ['A','B','C','D']
lmit = 200

n = random.randint(1, lmit)

x = choice([i for i in range(0,9) if i not in exclude])

print(x)
```

Necesito generar un código al azar que empiece con alguna de las letras de la lista `let` y un número al azar teniendo como límite la variable `lmit`, sin embargo hay que tener algo en cuenta y es que el valor final generado no puede ser igual a alguno almacenado en la lista `exclude`, hasta ahora solo he logrado lo que ven, que en realidad no es nada y es algo, porque creo que lo unico que le faltaría es de alguna manera unir una letra aleatoria y un numero aleatorio y pasarlos al ciclo for de más abajo y verificar que no exista en la lista `exclude`, la verdad no se como proseguir desde aquí, quizás exista una manera más Pythonica de hacerlo, gracias de antemano. En la parte de `i for i in range(0,9)` está así porque ese pedazo de código lo saqué de otro lugar.

### EDIT (AVANCE)

```
exclude = ['A9', 'B2', 'C18']
let = ['A','B','C','D']
lmit = 200

def Select():
    ltr = random.choice(let)
    nmr = random.randint(1, lmit)
    code = '{}{}'.format(ltr, nmr)

    return code

while Select() not in exclude:
    print(Select())
    break
```

Hice esto pero sigue sin parecerme la mejor manera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea inicial que tienes está bastante bien, puedes hacer las siguiente mejoras.

1. **Añadir los parámetros a tu función**, para que pertenezcan al contexto de la función y no estén en el contesto global.
2. **Documentar tu función** para que tanto tu *"yo del futuro"* como otros puedan saber que hace.
3. Introducirlo todo dentro de la misma función, ya que pertenece todo a una misma funcionalidad, no tiene sentido sacar el `while` fuera.
4. Poner errores personalizados con `raise`.
5. En vez de `format()` que puede confundir ya que se suele usar con `print()` y hacer pensar que quiere imprimir algo, puedes usar `str` para convertir el número a *string* y después concatenarlo con el operador suma `+`.

Tu función quedaría así, **te quedo comentarios explicativos en el código**:

```
import random

exclude = ['A9', 'B2', 'C18']
let = ['A','B','C','D']
lmit = 200

#Le pasamos los parámetros necesarios a la función y damos una pista sobre su tipo
def Select(let:list, lmit:int, exclude:list) -> str:
#Creamos la documentación de dicha función
    """
Función que gener un valor al azar con parámetros determinados.

Parámetros:
-----------

let: list
    Lista de letras por la que debe empezar nuestro código generado

lmit: int
    Número máximo aleatorio que se puede generar para nuestro código

exclude: defecto = None
    lista de códigos que no pueden ser generados

return
-------
Un código al azar que no se encuentre en la lista de valores excluidos
    """

#Creamos errores personalizados, en este caso le decimos que la lista no debe estar vacia
    if not exclude or not let:
        raise ValueError("Las listas entregadas no pueden estar vacias")

#El número elegido para crear números aleatorios no puede ser inferior a 2
    if lmit < 2:
        raise ValueError("El límite debe de ser mayor de uno")

#Excogemos el primer código de la lista exclude para que funcione el while
    code = exclude[0]
    while code in exclude:
        ltr = random.choice(let)
        nmr = random.randint(1, lmit)
        code = ltr + str(nmr)
    return code

print(Select(let, lmit, exclude))
```

**Salida:** `C118`

Si quieres mejorarla todavía puedes hacer más cosas, como crearte un fichero llamado `_validations.py` y crear allí una función, que gestione los errores personalizados.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos, la verdad es que el código ahora se ve mejor, algo que me falta mucho es aprender a refactorizar el código, aún tengo códigos que aunque sirven son muy largos y complejos, y en ocasiones al pedir ayuda resulta que se puede hacer en 2 o 3 lineas jaja